# jGit constructor error

Tags: git, groovy, jgit

In code below I got the following error: `Could not find matching constructor for: org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk(org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git)`. I want to check the author last commit, if it will be John, remove that file. What is wrong?

```
def badAuthor = 'John'

def authorEqual() {

Git git = Git.open(new File(".git"))  
RevCommit lastCommit = null;   
    try {
        RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(git) --> HERE ERROR
        RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(head.getObjectId());
        PersonIdent aAuthort = commit.getAuthorIdent()
        if(commit.getAuthorIdent().getWhen().equals(aAuthor == BadAuthor).compareTo(
            lastCommit.getAuthorIdent().getWhen()) > 0)
                lastCommit = commit
                println commit
                git.rm.call() 
    } 
     finally {      
            println "Commit ok"
    }
}
authorEqual()
```

Comment: Could you please try: `RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(git.repository)` ?

Comment: yep, that's it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [docs](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.8.0.201706111038-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevWalk.html#RevWalk-org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository-) `RevWalk` accepts an instance of `Repository` in constructor. `Repository` can be obtained from `Git` instance, have a look [here](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.8.0.201706111038-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/Git.html#getRepository--).